Looking for a numerical algorithm or library to calculate derivatives of degenerate eigenvalues.
There is a well known result to easily calculate the derivative of non degenerate eigenvalues :
$$ v_p^T \frac{dA}{dx} v_p = \frac{de_p}{dx} \space\space \space(1)$$
But when they are degenerate, how is it possible to calculate numerically these derivatives ?
To sum up the problem (as far as I can understand). If matrix A is considered,
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & x \\x & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
The eigenvalues and the normalized eigenvectors are :
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Lambda}} = \begin{pmatrix}1+x & 0 \\0 & 1-x\end{pmatrix} 
,\space\space\space\space
\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{dA}}}{dx}} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
If x=0 (degenerate eigenvalues) 
$$ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{\Lambda}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
If $\space\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V1}}$ is used in eq. (1), the result is valid. But, if another eigenvectors are used, for example :
$$\boldsymbol{\mathsf{V2}} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
(or any linear combination of them), eq.(1) does not hold.
The purpose of this very simple analytical example is only to illustrate my problem.
Now, I come to my problem : $ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$ is a large matrix (1000x1000). Eigenvalues and eigenvectors could be numerically calculated with Lapack library. An analytical expression is known for $ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{dA}}}{dx}} $.
But how can I calculate $ \mathsf{\frac{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{d\Lambda}}}{dx}} $ with the best numerical precision ? Indeed, eigenvalues could be degenerate but, because of numerical precision problem, when are thy considered as degenerate ? And if they are degenerate, how the optimum linear combination of eigenvectors (calculated with Lapack library from $ \boldsymbol{\mathsf{A}}$) could be determined ?
I wonder if there is a library to perform such numerical calculation ? If not, what are the algorithm generally used ?
Thanks for answer.

Maybe better luck asking here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/
